# Activity ends on HOME button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

I have weird problem with HOME button.
I have two activities A and B.

A always starts B...like this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.test.B"), 0);
```

and listening for result for finishing the whole app...but that i think doesn't matter.

When I'm in B activity, and hit the HOME button...and on long press of HOME button get back.
Activity A is shown instead of B...

Why is that happening? Any idea? Should I set something in Manifest?
It looks to like activity B is finished...but i dont want that. I want B to be shown...

Here is some code from A activity:

```
// Start new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And here is some code from manifest:

```
<activity
        android:label="A"
        android:name=".A"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.uno_manager.A" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="B"
        android:name=".B"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.uno_manager.B" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have activity one activity before those two...that represents splash screen.

In activity B I have overridden `onRestoreInstance` and `onInstanceSave` methods. And on some click I call `setResult` and `finish()` to exit the app. But I don't think that have anything to do with this.

I've tried to comment whole code from B activity. I've left only `setContentView` in `onCreate` method. And the same thing happened on HOME button.

Comment: interesting, I created a test project and tried but worked for me? The difference is I tried like this: 
    `Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent = new Intent(this, Test2.class);    
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file add launchMode attributes to your activities. 
See this link for more information to reuse 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

I think anything apart from `standard` would work for your requirement, but see the documentation for full information or experiment with them to find out the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `android:noHistory="true"` from activity B. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html): "The activity's finish() method is called when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen"